# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end when loading any page where this portion of the script is called

Tags: php

This is part of an xml file that gets parsed modifying sections of the page as it loads. The modified version is cached and displayed by the virtual engine so the actual template files don't get modified.

```
    <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/product.tpl">
    <operation error="skip">
        <search position="before"><![CDATA[
        <?php if ($price) { ?>
        ]]></search>
        <add trim="true"><![CDATA[
        <?php if ($call_price < 1) { ?>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation error="skip">
        <search position="before" index="1"><![CDATA[
        <?php if ($options) { ?>
        ]]></search>
        <add trim="true"><![CDATA[
        <?php } else { ?>
        <?php if ($call_price) { ?>
        <div class="description" style="border-top:none; margin-top:0px;">
        <?php echo $text_call_price; ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation error="skip">
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
        <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" id="button-cart" class="button" />
        ]]></search>
        <add trim="true"><![CDATA[
        <?php if ($disable_button < 1) { ?>
        <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" id="button-cart" class="button" />          
        <?php } else { ?>
        <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" id="button-cart" class="button" style="background-image:none; background-color:#CCC;" disabled="disabled" />
        <?php } ?>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Comment: I'd guess you have an unclosed brace somewhere in there.

Comment: `<?php if ($price)  ?>` and `<?php if ($call_price < 1)  ?>` ??????

Comment: Use an IDE with bracket matching.  See also [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071)/

Comment: Those should have been there, original code there now. Furthermore I've search for missing brackets but just don't see it.

Comment: @user2719578 I see 7 opening braces (`{`) but only 5 closing ones (`}`) in your code snippet.

Comment: I've got it missing div class...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you haven't closed these if statements:

```
    <?php if ($price) { ?>
    ...
    <?php if ($call_price < 1) { ?>
```